# How insert a blob in SQL Server without bulk and using ASP?

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, blob

I need to upload files 'into' a SQL Server database.

I need a solution that doesn't involve **bulk** inserts.

Comment: The Google search is a bit difficult, but this link looks promising: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/52bd61f5-1ab6-4b7b-855c-238149c751bb/, using ordinary ADO.NET.

Comment: unfortunately this old server works with classic asp

Comment: Then you need to be searching for VBSCRIPT or VB6 code.  Something like this: http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=169654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Set ObjStr = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
ObjStr.Type = 1 'AdBinary
ObjStr.Open

ObjStr.LoadFromFile "D:\file.pdf"

'Evita sql inject
Set oPreparedStatementADO              = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oPreparedStatementADO.ActiveConnection = conexao
cSql = "INSERT INTO edital_editais(blob_field) values (?); "


oPreparedStatementADO.CommandText = cSQL

x = ObjStr.Read

oPreparedStatementADO.Parameters.Item(0) = x

set rs = oPreparedStatementADO.Execute
```