# How to add picture or movie into sql server database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

How to store the pictures and Movies in sql-server 2008 database

I want to make a database with pictures and front view as vb.net using Website.

Comment: Consider using the BLOB data type: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017521/how-insert-a-blob-in-sql-server-without-bulk-and-using-asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Use `FILESTREAM`

Since you've specified SQL Server 2008 as you database of choice what you're after is `FILESTREAM` capability that it supports.

Here's a [basic Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) about it and a more [advanced one on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx) that also includes speed comparison to storing data directly in database.

Comment: I dont understand what you are saying? Please explain me briefly

Comment: Thank you for giving. It is very helpful to Bignners